# Why can't I use an NSInteger in a switch statement?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, switch-statement, nsinteger

Why doesn't this work:

```
NSInteger sectionLocation = 0;
NSInteger sectionTitles = 1;
NSInteger sectionNotifications = 2;

switch (section) {
    case sectionLocation:
        //
        break;
    case sectionTitles:
        //
        break;
    case sectionNotifications:
        // 
        break;
    default:
        //
}
```

I get this compile error:

> error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant

Is it not possible to use NSInteger's like this? If so, is there another way to use variables as cases in a switch statement? `sectionLocation` etc. have variable values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem isn't the scalar type, but that the case labels may change value when they are variables like that.

For all intents and purposes, the compiler compiles a switch statement as a set of gotos.   The labels can't be variable.

Use an enumerated type or #defines.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that the compiler will often want to create a 'jump table' using the switch value as the key into that table and it can only do that if it's switching on a simple integer value.  This should work instead:

```
#define sectionLocation  0
#define sectionTitles  1
#define sectionNotifications 2

int intSection = section;

switch (intSection) {
    case sectionLocation:
        //
        break;
    case sectionTitles:
        //
        break;
    case sectionNotifications:
        // 
        break;
    default:
        //
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you are using variables. You can only use constants in switch statements.

Do something like

```
#define SOME_VALUE 1
```

or

```
enum Values {
    valuea = 1,
    valueb = 2,
    ...
}
```

And you will be able to use valuea and so forth in your switch statement.

Comment: So I'll have to resort to if-else-if-else again? Isn't there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, use defines, whats the problem with that? :D

Answer (score 1):

If your case values truly change at runtime, that's what the if...else if...else if construct is there for.

Answer (score -2):

or just do this

```
switch((int)secion)
```